# Is there any common NoSQLTemplate in spring

Tags: java, spring, nosql

Just like Statement, [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in core java, [JdbcTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) in spring is there any common accessor for NoSQL from below list.

- MongoDB
- Neo4J
- Elasticsearch
- Solr
- Redis
- Gemfire or Geode
- Cassandra
- Couchbase
- LDAP

Comment: No, there isn't one, because most NoSQL databases use their own specific drivers and engines.  That being said, for example MongoDB has its own Spring template, but it basically only works with Mongo, not other NoSQL databases.

Comment: There are libraries like spring data mongodb  and respectively for other dbs as well  -https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#reference ,https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-couchbase ,you can extend the provided methods ,they provide out of box implementation for the job

Answer (score 0):

JNoSQL (http://www.jnosql.org/) tries to provide a common interface to access multiple NoSQL databases

Comment: Thanks for your input. This is the closest one.